# Save axios login credentials for subsequent calls in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am trying to use axios to log in to an account on the web,

the website will return a cookie.

axios should store this cookie.

And whenever I make any call to this website after that, it should send this cookie with every request to verify that it's logged in.

I searched on the web, and I found that the option `withCredentials: true` does that.

However, I tried it, but it's not working.

You see in the example, even though in step 1 I am successfully logging in,

when I try to create a user, it shows me that it's failed.

If you looked into the responded HTML for the fail message, you'll see that it sent you back to the login page. So it thinks you're not logged in.

Please use the code sandbox example I provided to see it in real live example.

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const examlpeHost = 'http://radmandemo.dmasoftlab.com'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: examlpeHost,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
})

// * Step 1. Login:

const loginEnpoint = '/admin.php?cont=login'
const loginRes = await axiosInstance.post(loginEnpoint, {
  managername: 'admin',
  password: '1111',
  md5: '27780bc84ff5136090c9b33063c0d38f', // password
})
// check to see if login successful based on the returned html
const loginResHtml = loginRes.data
const isSuccessLogin = loginResHtml.includes(
  `<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=admin.php">`
)
if (isSuccessLogin) console.log('[success ✅] login successful!')
else throw new Error('[fail ❌] Login failed!')

// * Step 2. create user:
const createUserEndpoint = '/admin.php?cont=store_user'
const createUserRes = await axiosInstance.post(createUserEndpoint, {
  username: 'test_user123456789',
  password1: '1111',
  password2: '1111',
  srvid: 0,
})
// check to see if create user successful based on the returned html
const createUserResHtml = createUserRes.data
const isSuccessCreateUser = createUserResHtml.includes('Account registered')
if (isSuccessCreateUser) console.log('[success ✅] create user successful!')
else console.log('[fail ❌] create user failed!')
```

[View on Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/axios-save-cookie-szzfnf)

[image]

What am I doing wrong? It worked with me when I was using [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent), but now in axios it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you setting a global content-type header for all requests? Only requests with bodies require it

Comment: Cross-origin cookies require specific configuration on the **server-side**. Specifically... CORS support, an `https://` URL, the `Secure` cookie attribute and `SameSite=None` cookie attribute. Do you manage the server-side process at all? if so, how have you configured it? If not, well I think you're out of luck

Comment: @Phil, I don't think it's related to CORS, I managed to make it work perfectly with superagent, actually currently my project is based on superagent, and it works. it's just not working with axios

Comment: Where is this code running, in Node.js or in the browser?

Comment: @Phil, in nodejs, no browser, it's a server side application\

Comment: Right, that would have made things much clearer earlier on. A quick search turns up this handy utility ~ [axios-cookiejar-support](https://github.com/3846masa/axios-cookiejar-support#readme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Phil, I used this [axios-cookiejar-support](https://axios-cookiejar-support) package to solve this issue:

```bash
$ npm install axios
$ npm install tough-cookie
$ npm install axios-cookiejar-support
```

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { wrapper } from 'axios-cookiejar-support';
import { CookieJar } from 'tough-cookie';

const jar = new CookieJar();
const client = wrapper(axios.create({ jar, withCredentials: true }));

await client.post('https://example.com/login', { username, password });
// now the cookie is saved, and you can use it, you're now logged in:
await client.post('https://example.com/orders', { item, qty });
```

Answer (score 3):

According to Axios source code they just bypassing `withCredentials` flag to the XHR Request which means that Node.JS adapter implementation doesn't support this pieces of functionality.

I think there is a pretty simple way you can fulfill your needs

#### Implement Axios interceptors

The idea is write interceptors:

1. Response interceptor for catching for `set-cookie` headers in responses, extract cookies and store them.
2. Request interceptor for set the `cookie` when the one is stored.

Here is a simple implementation of interceptors:

```js
// Cookies in a map format, e.g {session: "xxyyzz"}
const cookies = {};

// Request interceptor. Set cookies if there are some.
const setCookies = (config) => {
    if (Object.keys(cookies).length) {
        // Format cookies string, e.g "session=xxyyzz; token=123"
        const cookiesStr = Object.keys(cookies).map((key) => `${key}=${cookies[key]}`).join('; ');

        config.headers['Cookie'] = cookieStr;
    }
    return config;
}

// Response interceptor. Extract cookies and store them.
const extractCookies = (config) => {
    if (config.headers['set-cookie']) {
        // Parse cookies headers, e.g {'set-cookie': [{session: "xxyyzz; ..."}]}
        config.headers['set-cookie'].forEach((cookie) => {
            const [key, value] = cookie.split(';')[0].split('=');
            cookies[key] = value;
        });
    }
    return config;
};
```

You can use this interceptors the following way:

```js
// Globally, for all Axios requests
axios.interceptors.response.use(setCookies);
axios.interceptors.response.use(extractCookies);

// For the specific instance
const axiosInstance = axios.create({...});
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(setCookie);
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(extractCookies);
```

NOTE: This is a pretty simple way of doing this. Ideally the solution should take into account cookie TTL, domain, and path.

I hope it would answer your question. Let me know if I need clarify anything.

Comment: so axios in itself was not designed to support node and to only work in browsers?

Comment: It does, but if you check their code, they have different implementation per platform: xhr for browser https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.x/lib/adapters/xhr.js and http for node https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.x/lib/adapters/http.js. In the latter they doesn't process `withCredentials` in any way.

Comment: So could we issue a bug/feature request to axios?

Comment: It looks like they're have an opened PR for adding `fetch` adapter which should fix the problem: https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/5146